# I'm here or I have been here

Tags: grammar

I'm here for 10 minutes

or

I have been here for 10 Minutes

what is the meaning of two sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm here for 10 minutes

indicates that the entire duration of my stay "here" will be 10 minutes; that is, I arrived at some point (less than 10 minutes ago), I am here now, and I will depart 10 minutes after my arrival time.

> I have been here for 10 minutes

indicates that 10 minutes have passed since I arrived "here"; that is, the time at which I arrived was 10 minutes in the past.  It implies nothing about when I may depart.

There's also

> I'm here for 10 more minutes

which says that I arrived at some point in the past (it doesn't imply anything about how long ago that was), I am here now, and I will depart 10 minutes from now.